# Craft 3 language switcher with same domain

Tags: craft3, localization, multi-site

Is it possible to create a multi language website in same domain?

In the admin settings, I created a second site with the same domain, but with a different site language.

```
templates/
├── index.twig      --> default homepage template
└── de/
    └── index.twig  --> German homepage template
```

and the on section settings for second site Template `de/index`

How can I toggle specific parts of my templates, depending on the chosen language?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm following... you want to create a Site1 at site.com and a German Site2 and site.com/de?